# Chef - Ohai Search On Another Org

Tags: chef-infra

Is it possible to search for values using an Ohai search in my cookbook from to specify a different organization to retrieve the results from.

I use a search like the on below to retrieve information about nodes in our own chef org but I would like to use a similar ohai search to find information about nodes on a different chef org.  Is it possible to configure this search and specify a different organization?

```
my_var= search(:node, "chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND role:my-role_name",
    filter_result: { 'ipaddress' => ['ipaddress'],
    'fqdn' => ['fqdn']
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

theoretically speaking, i think you can do that by reloading [chef-client configuration](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html) that matches the other chef-server\organization...

```
require 'chef'
Chef::Config.from_file '/path/to/config.rb'
```

though, i strongly recommended not to do it.

Comment: I feel the same way.  It might work but probably not the best solution.  I was thinking about configuring my recipe to make an api to call the chef server to get the config I need.  If I figure out how to do that I'll post the response.

Comment: @Chris: maybe it is time for you to use some key-value store, such as [hashicorp valut](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/using-hashicorps-vault-with-chef) or utilize your attribute correctly.